# Inheriting from custom classes within models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Just curious on how things autoloading works in rails

```
app/models/base_facebook_object.rb

class BaseFacebookObject
end
```

In the file where I require it,

```
app/models/fb_campaign.rb

class FbCampaign < BaseFacebookObject
end
```

But the above doesn't work as it says BaseFacebookObject not defined?

Do I always have to require the base object file in such cases?

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/base_facebook_object"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `class` instead of `Class`

Comment: According to the rails guide, it should be autoloaded: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-availability

Answer (score 0):

The autoloader will resolve unfound constant. In your case if you call `FbCampaign` it will check for the file `fb_campaign.rb`, then during the loading will find `BaseFacebookObject` and load `base_facebook_object.rb`

In other words, no requires needed. Actually you should never use require in a RoR application except for std lib not yet loaded  (eg. securerandom, base64 etc. ) or files into a lib/non-autoloaded path.